# how to get date ,year , month from datetime using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the year, month, date, hour, and minutes from a `datetime` in Javascript. This is my code:

```
var newdatestring=document.getElementById("2012-12-11 10:36").value;
var newdate=new Date(newdatestring);

newdate.setMinutes ( newdate.getMinutes() + 30 );
var formdate=newdate.getYear()+"-"+(newdate.getMonth()+1)+"-"+newdate.getDate()+" "+newdate.getHours()+":"+newdate.getMinutes();

alert(formdate);
```

this code working fine in Chrome and Opera browsers, but it doesn't work in IE or Firefox. In those browsers, it shows something like `Nan-Nan-Nan Nan:Nan`.

Comment: Maybe your problem is in the html... That doesn't look like a valid id, there shouldn't be any spaces or start with a number...

Comment: Why do you have an HTML element id named after a specific time? Are you using dynamic html forms or is that a static date?

Comment: "Nan-Nan-Nan Nan:Nan ... batman!"

Comment: ^^ [WAT](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)!?

Comment: @elclanrs I'm glad you've recognized the most important part of the talk heh.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var month = newdate.getUTCMonth();
var day = newdate.getUTCDate();
var year = newdate.getUTCFullYear();
```

when `newdate` is the date `object`